# One combobox cannot add all its items into MS Access database

Tags: java, ms-access-2010

```
>  [i want to add all combobox items in MSAccess database]
```

I want to do this
I want to add every items of one combobox into MSAccess database for e.g. I want
to do that my combo has 4 fields one,two,three,four and database has four fields route1,route2,route3,route4...I want to set as route1=one, route2= two....etc.

```
if(e.getSource()==btn_save)
{
    try{

         Connection con;

         DriverManager.registerDriver(new sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver());

         Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

         con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:dsnproj","","");

         Statement s1 = con.createStatement();

         String q1="insert dest,route1,route2,route3,route4 into trans_dest values(
                    '"+cmb_dest.getSelectedItem()+"',
                    '"+cmb_route.getItem(1)+"',
                    '"+cmb_route.getItem(2)+"',
                    '"+cmb_route.getItem(3)+"',
                    '"+cmb_route.getItem(4)+"')";

         s1.execute(q1);


         }

         catch(Exception ae)
         {
             System.out.println(ae);
         }
    }
}
```

[i got error as]
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 >= 4

Comment: item starts with 0, not with 1.

Comment: hey by this, it adds items in combobox but dont insert in database

Comment: possible duplicate of [one combobox cannot add all it's items into ms access database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201220/one-combobox-cannot-add-all-its-items-into-ms-access-database)